# eval or alternative to call an object through a variable inside then() inside a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eval

I import 'Bank' in a function, and i want to use inside in then().

I'm using eval(table) but i get th error: ReferenceError: Bank is not defined',

```
import {  Bank } from './ormconnectors';

const genericResolver = ( table, action , values ) => {

  if (action==='list') {

    const errors = [];
    return Auth.isAuthenticated()
      .then(() => {
        return eval(table).findAll()
     }
   }
 }
```

calling this function:

```
genericResolver  ( 'Bank', ..... );
```

Comment: What's your framework for ES6 modules? In which environment does the code run, is it transpiled, how are modules loaded, are the modules bundled?

Comment: I run with nodemon ./server.js --exec babel-node -e js

Comment: if I insert 'const Bank2=Bank;' inside genericResolve() , and the paremeter table is 'Bank2' then works

Comment: Yes, the way babel resolves imports is not compatible with `eval`. A local variable sounds like a proper workaround.

Comment: thanks, I've really forgot about babel, thinking is es6 direct, hope in the future everybody works without babel, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you need `eval` for though. What is `table` and why do you need to pass code as a string?

Comment: Bank is just an example, i want to operate with all my tables in dynamic way to  methods with orm sequelize to add, update actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `eval` at all?

You should instead [switch to accessing properties by name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Accessing_member_properties):

```
import {  Bank } from './ormconnectors';
const tableByName = {"Bank": Bank};

...

        return tableByName[table].findAll()
```

Comment: I think this is the solution, but it's in ./ormconnectors' where I must  put all the tables connectors and then import just a variable and use like you wrote

Comment: Right, doing it this way makes even more sense.